# export and import docker data containers

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and I have a problem when it comes to shipping data containers. Ok, usually we ship images and users can start as may containers from this image as the want, right?

Now I want to ship some data too - so I have made a data container so:

```
docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata phusion/baseimage
```

Next I simply started a bash and inserted some data into my data container

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata -i -t phusion/baseimage /bin/bash
echo "foo" > /dbdata/bar.txt
exit
```

Now I want to allow my team members to use the same data (offline), so I would like to "send" my data container to them. Therefore I have used

```
docker export dbdata > /tmp/cool_data.tar
```

But when I re import this with

```
cat /tmp/data.tar | sudo docker import - dbdata2
```

I can not use this "container" because it seems to be an image

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata2 -i -t phusion/baseimage /bin/bash
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Container dbdata2 not found. Impossible to mount its volumes
```

How do I export and import data containers correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't export and import data in volumes like this - volumes are simply not included in export/import.

You don't need to do this however - just zip or tar the directories the volumes are mapped to and send to your colleagues. They can then make their own data containers using those files.

You may also want to look at [flocker](https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker), which can help you migrate containers and data.

Comment: This is indeed true but it would be very great if you could just pull different sets of data as easy as images. But it seems that you have to use something like docker-backup or flocker (which seems to be a big framework for a very simple use case).

Comment: @KIC: One thing you could do is write a Dockerfile which copies in the data to a directory and *afterwards* declares the directory as a volume. You will then be able to use that image to create a data container and it will be seeded with the data that was in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a container out of this image first. Run this:

```
docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata2 dbdata2
```

For more details, check out [Creating and mounting Data Volume Containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)

Comment: interestingly I get an exception on this: FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: No command specified

Comment: You need to provide a fake command like "/sbin/my_init", but the problem is, the /dbdata folder is empty afterwards, so no data got transfered at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having good luck with the following Dockerfile:

```
from scratch

ADD install_theGreatSoftwarePkg /install
VOLUME /install
```

Then I do a build and create:

```
docker build -t greatSoftwareInstallImage .
docker create -t --name=greatSoftwareMedia greatSoftwareInstallImage /bin/true
```